# Mongoose converting stored UTC dates to local time?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm wondering if this is normal, or if I'm missing something in the schema setup or query process:

My app, and mongoose, is correctly storing a date as UTC in mongodb. This is confirmed by viewing the documents via the mongo shell. When I retrieve the documents from mongodb via mongoose the date is now local time.

Is there a way to have mongoose keep the date as UTC when queried?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mongoose and node.js aren't doing anything to your dates, it's simply that the JavaScript `Date` type produces a local time string when you call `toString()` on it even though it actually contains the time in UTC.

Explicitly call `toUTCString()` on your `Date` object if you want a UTC time string.

Comment: Gotcha. After logging the query results a few different ways I found out that it was console.log that was showing the dates in local time, therefor it much be calling toString(). Good to know going forward... Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

The timestamps are stored timezone agnostically, as a unix timestamp. This timestamp will work across timezones, and node interprets it using your current timezone. You can retrieve the UTC value from the date object using the getUTC* methods such as get getUTCHours()

Comment: Thanks for the response, I understand I can convert it UTC and work with it from there. I just seemed a little strange that mongoose and/or node automatically brings it into local time. Maybe the better question is: can I explicitly tell node to use UTC... similar to the date_default_timezone_set function in PHP or other languages?

Comment: @DM Are you putting things into mongoose in UTC, or in your local time? You may be able to change node's timezone using process.env.TZ, but it's not recommended. https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3286