# How to correctly jsonify a mongoose model with a birthday?

Tags: json, date, mongoose

How can I store a birthday like `09/14/1986` with mongoose and convert it to json with
[`toJSON`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON) while ignoring the timezone?

Assume you have a schema like

```
schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  birthday: Date
});
```

and you store the birthday above, `mongoose` actually stores it as `Date(527032800000)`. Now when you call `toJSON` on the model it is converted with `JSON.stringify`. `Date`s are converted to a string with `toISOString` which results in `1986-09-13T22:00:00.000Z` (on a machine with a german timezone setting: `Europe/Berlin`). As you can see, this is not the date we might expect for a birthday because the timezone is interpreted (See a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596804/mongoose-converting-stored-utc-dates-to-local-time)).

What to do? I don't want to lose the comfort of parsing various birthdaystrings and the use of mongoose's `toJSON`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the way your date gets created.
I suggest you use dates in UTC-time for such data as birthdays, which would allow you to use UTC-times throughout the system.

You can either:

- set the date in UTC in the constructor, supplying to it a string in UTC:
  `new Date('1986-09-14T00:00:00.000Z');`
- use `new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0));` to create a Date-object from an integer year, month and day.

So, the answer is: you should **store UTC date in *birthday* field** when you create/update the model.